# How to get a value from a HTML text area in the Play Framework?

Tags: html, playframework, scala-template

I am using scala templates within the Play Framework to create my views.

The user is required to enter some text into a text area. I would like to use this text to send into another view within my application.

```
<div class="ui form">
 <div class="field">
   <label>Please use the text box below</label>
     <textarea>//this is the text that i need to grab</textarea>
 </div>
    @pet_order(petId, //this is where i send in the text)
</div>
```

Can anyone give me some advice on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text area must be wrapped into a form and have the `name` attribute.

Html will look like this:

```
  <form action="/some_path" method="post">
    <textarea name="attribute_name"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
  </form>
```

You can use Play Framework's helpers to create a form in the view. Something like:

```
@helper.form(action = routes.YourController.your_action) {
   @helper.textarea(myForm("attribute_name")) 
}
```

Read more [here](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaForms)

When you submit the form, the text from the text area will be sent to the server to a certain `Controller#action`. The url of the action is specified in the form's `action` attribute. The name of the parameter that will hold the entered text is specified in the textarea's `name` attribute.

Then, in the `action` you have to extract the text from request attributes by it's name and send it to another view whether renderig the view and passing the text as a parameter or redirecting to another `Controller#action` passing the text as a parameter of the new request.

You can use Play Framework's [Form](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/play/api/data/Form.html) to extract request parameters. See the previous link.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation - i actually ended up doing this in the end so it is the correct answer. One small thing that i had to figure out - i had a single int variable that i wanted to also send in with the form. The way i went about this was to add a new field to the form, add the value of the variable to that field (value = "my value") and then make the made the field "invisible" by hiding it. This allowed me to send the variable with the form